# How to config Redis as session storage with KrakenJS

Tags: node.js, session, connect-redis

With Express, I can use Redis as session storage like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    store: new RedisStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
    db: 'test',
    pass: '123456'
  }),
  secret: '123456789'
}));
```

But with Kraken, the session configuration is in the file `config/middleware.json`. I changed the file to use `connect-redis` as following:

```
{
    "middleware": {
        "session": {
           "module": "connect-redis",
           "secret": "99b91c387e6e049308fc31d3cfff5fd3149e419c"
        }
    }
}
```

This way, Kraken does use Redis as session storage but how am I supposed to pass Redis' options (password, host, db name...) like with Express?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation for kraken-js is not very extensive. Hope it improves.

We had to dig into the code and understand the logic and we were able to solve.

Hope this help others who want to use Redis Session store with Kraken.js

Add "connect-redis" to package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "connect-redis": ">=1.0.0"
},
```

Install "connect-redis" module

```
npm install
```

In the config/middleware.json add the config as below

```
{
    "middleware": {
        "session": {
            "module": "connect-redis",
            "config": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 6379,
                "db": 1
            },
            "secret": "a1df0e81ef54d199567befb02761b1834c8b7406"
        }
    }
}
```

Change the config as required

Start/Restart server and it should work!

Provided you already have Redis running

Comment: Good answer,
I'll make an example out of this to post on the Kraken site.

Answer (score 2):

A complete working example can be found here:
https://github.com/AlexSantos/Kraken_Example_Session_Redis